# A short alternative to describe a location very close to the city

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I've racked my brains to no avail trying to find a correct and practical term to describe a location very close to the city centre (of the little town).

"Close to the city" is very cliche and sounds very generic, of course.

So how would paraphrase "XXX very to the city centre" in possibly better words?

Comment: how about 'suburbia'?

Comment: I need to find an alternative to define the distance, not the town.

Comment: Like *a stone's throw from* the city center?

Comment: @Kris Where exactly do you live?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not in a glass house.

Comment: I live in İzmir and talking about Alaçatı...

Comment: The 'distance to travel is time' metaphor is often used: 'just a copuple of minutes from the towm centre' (walking implied); 'half an hour from the town centre' (other transport).

Comment: Using "minutes" so as to describe the distance would be a good choice... Thanks, Ashworth

Comment: How about: Inner city?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Near the middle *or* near the centre

Depending on the actual geographic location you could state "just south of the centre of town" (insert appropriate direction).  In larger cities, the terms **south-central** ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historic_South_Central_Los_Angeles)) or the like are employed.  There is no reason to my knowledge not to use it for a smaller city.

Answer (score 2):

For a small town, you could say:

- a **"five/ten/fifteen-minute walk"** from city-center, or **"within walking distance".**

Even if the listener intends to use a car or a bike, he will have a good idea of how far it is.

For larger cities you'd better use other parameters such as the time spent by subway or by car.